# Get method asynchronous in web app with nodejs and redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, web-applications

I'm new to nodejs and redis and I'm trying to create a web app have which should get recent tweets containing a set hashtag and pattern :

```
const twitterClient = require('./init')
var counts = 0;
var tweet_array_IDs = [];
var hashtag_search = "covid";
var pattern = "vaccine";
var redis = require("redis"),
    redisClient;

redisClient = redis.createClient({
    legacyMode: true,
});

redisClient.connect();

redisClient.get(pattern, function (err, tweet_counts){

    if (err !== null){
    
        //gestisci l'errore
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    }

    if (tweet_counts === null)
        counts = 0;
    else
        counts = parseInt(tweet_counts, 10);
        
});

var get_recent_tweet = function(hashtag_search, pattern){

    twitterClient.tweets.search({
        q: '#' + hashtag_search,
        result_type: 'recent', //get latest tweets with this hashtag
    }).then ((response) => {
        var tweet_array = response.statuses;
        tweet_array.forEach(function (tweet){           
            // if current tweet is not in the list, add it
            if (tweet_array_IDs.indexOf(tweet.id) === -1){
                tweet_array_IDs.push(tweet.id);
                if (tweet.text.indexOf(pattern) > -1){
                                counts++;
                                redisClient.incr(pattern);
                        }
            }
        });


    }).catch ((err) => console.error(err));
}


setInterval(function () {
    get_recent_tweet(hashtag_search, pattern);  
    module.exports = counts;
}, 3000);
```

My question is the following, I've read that the get method() in nodejs is asynchronous so should the get_recent_tweet function be placed inside the callback function of the redisClient.get() method ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. You can also use `async/await` to make your code more readable and handle asynchronous operations in a synchronous-like manner. Here's how you can modify your code to use `async/await`:

```js
async function main() {
    try {
        const tweet_counts = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            redisClient.get(pattern, (err, tweet_counts) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error:", err);
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(tweet_counts);
            });
        });

        if (tweet_counts === null) {
            counts = 0;
        } else {
            counts = parseInt(tweet_counts, 10);
        }

        // Now call the function to get recent tweets after retrieving counts from Redis
        await get_recent_tweet(hashtag_search, pattern);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}

async function get_recent_tweet(hashtag_search, pattern) {
    try {
        const response = await twitterClient.tweets.search({
            q: '#' + hashtag_search,
            result_type: 'recent', //get latest tweets with this hashtag
        });
        
        const tweet_array = response.statuses;
        tweet_array.forEach(function (tweet){           
            // if current tweet is not in the list, add it
            if (tweet_array_IDs.indexOf(tweet.id) === -1){
                tweet_array_IDs.push(tweet.id);
                if (tweet.text.indexOf(pattern) > -1){
                    counts++;
                    redisClient.incr(pattern);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}

setInterval(async function () {
    await main();
    module.exports = counts;
}, 3000);

// Call main function initially to start the process
main();
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that Node Redis also started supporting async/await in version 4 as well. So you can get rid of even more callbacks!